# DOMException Error when splitting large file blob into chunks

Tags: javascript, blob, large-files, chunking, domexception

can someone please help me to debug this function

```js
const chunkify = async (file: Blob) => {
  const totalSize = file.size;
  const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100MB

  const chunks = [] as Uint8Array[];
  const amountOfChunks = Math.ceil(totalSize / chunkSize);

  console.log("Total blob size: ", totalSize);
  for (let index = 0; index < amountOfChunks; index++) {
    const start = index * chunkSize;
    const end = (index + 1) * chunkSize;

    console.log("Start point: ", start);
    console.log("End point: ", end);
    const chunk = await file.slice(start, end).arrayBuffer();
    chunks.push(new Uint8Array(chunk));
  }

  return chunks;
};
```

As an overview, the function above assuming a 0.97 GB file is provided through using Android WebView (with Ionic & Capacitor), executes approximately 7 times (actually 6, because on the 7th iteration the code stops at the last console.log() before returning the error below)

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired.
```

PS: I tried asking Bard this but and it suggested replacing

```js
const end = (index + 1) * chunkSize;
```

with

```js
const end = Math.min(totalSize, (index + 1) * chunkSize);
```

but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Why do you do this exactly? This way the whole file will be stuck in memory, when it could have stayed on the storage disk and read only when needed. Besides, what you are experiencing sounds like a browser bug, it *should* work (or fail with another reason)n so the best action might be to open an issue to its vendor.

Comment: I'm using this method because later on in the project I use @ffmpeg/ffmpeg to process the chunks in the browser

Comment: Can't you pass it a stream instead?

Comment: I've tried but I don't seem to have a decent knowledge of streams yet. The last thing I would want is to implement something I won't be able to debug or improve later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, kind of feeling dumb for not thinking of this but when I reduce the `chunkSize` variable to 10 MB (1024 * 1024 * 10) it works.

JavaScript is weird

PS: Other solutions are also welcome

Edit: I later edited the function to calculate the chunkSize based on the - blob size / video duration